# Error in simple HTML5/ JQuery game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on a fairly simple game which resembles whack a mole but instead uses snakes. I've tried and tried but can't work out why the game won't start when I try and open it through a browser. The problem seems to be with adding in the try_again feature as the game works fine until I try and add this facility but I can' t see exactly what the root cause is. Any help is gratefully received!

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

body{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.snake {
background-color: rgb(36, 176, 79);
border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 10%;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
background-image: url(snake.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

#snake1{ left:10%; }
#snake2{ left:45%; }
#snake3{ left:80%; }

.score{ font-family: arial; font-size: 5vw; position: absolute; right: 50%;}
</style>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var add = 0;

function game_over(){
                jQuery(".snake").stop().animate({"top";"100%"}, 300);
                jQuery(".score").html("Game Over Motherfucker!");
                jQuery(".score").append("<div class= 'try_again'>TRY AGAIN</div>");

}

function start(){
        add = 0;
        jQuery(".score").html("Score: " + add);
        jQuery(".snake").animate({"top": "0%"}, 5000, function(){
                game_over();
                jQuery(".try_again").click(function(){start();});
        });

}

jQuery(".snake").hover(function(){

    jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(hurt.png)");
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({"top":"100%"}, 300, function(){

        add = add - (-1);
        jQuery(".score").html("Score: " + add);
        jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(snake.png)");
        jQuery(".snake").animate({"top": "0%"}, 5000, function(){
                game_over();
                jQuery(".try_again").click(function(){start();});
        });

    });
});

start();
}

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="score"> Score: 0 </div>

<div class="snake" id="snake1"></div>
<div class="snake" id="snake2"></div>
<div class="snake" id="snake3"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors

1)   `jQuery(".snake").stop().animate({"top";"100%"}, 300);`

should be

```
  jQuery(".snake").stop().animate({"top":"100%"}, 300);
```

2)

```
start();
}//this is in addition you should remove it

});
</script>
```

Below is the fixed code :

```
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .snake {
      background-color: rgb(36, 176, 79);
      border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 10%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      background-image: url(snake.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
    }

    #snake1 {
      left: 10%;
    }

    #snake2 {
      left: 45%;
    }

    #snake3 {
      left: 80%;
    }

    .score {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 5vw;
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      var add = 0;

      function game_over() {
        jQuery(".snake").stop().animate({
          "top":"100%"
        }, 300);
        jQuery(".score").html("Game Over Motherfucker!");
        jQuery(".score").append("<div class= 'try_again'>TRY AGAIN</div>");

      }

      function start() {
        add = 0;
        jQuery(".score").html("Score: " + add);
        jQuery(".snake").animate({
          "top": "0%"
        }, 5000, function() {
          game_over();
          jQuery(".try_again").click(function() {
            start();
          });
        });

      }

      jQuery(".snake").hover(function() {

        jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(hurt.png)");
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({
          "top": "100%"
        }, 300, function() {

          add = add - (-1);
          jQuery(".score").html("Score: " + add);
          jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(snake.png)");
          jQuery(".snake").animate({
            "top": "0%"
          }, 5000, function() {
            game_over();
            jQuery(".try_again").click(function() {
              start();
            });
          });

        });
      });

      start();


    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="score"> Score: 0 </div>

  <div class="snake" id="snake1"></div>
  <div class="snake" id="snake2"></div>
  <div class="snake" id="snake3"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of syntax errors:

1)

```
$(".snake").stop().animate({"top";"100%"}, 300);
```

should be

```
$(".snake").stop().animate({"top":"100%"}, 300);
```

(replaced ; with :)

2)

```
start();
}
```

The } is an orphan and needs removing.

Correct those and it appears to work fine. You can see these errors for yourself by opening your browser developer tools (press F12 on most desktop browsers) and looking at the console. This should really be your first step when anything doesn't work.